# How can I use Sequelize in Ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework, sequelize.js

How can I use Sequelize + SQLite in Ionic?

I think `Sequelize` is a good library to connect to SQL DB.
Since it is written with JS, can we use it in Ionic with SQLite?

Comment: not sure why would you want such a library to operate on a client side. Does your app strongly requires SQL on client? or is it more of a preference? In Ionic ideally you want to leverage Ionic Storage as wrapper which turns all available persistence types to a simple key value storage api

Comment: In my project, it requires strong SQL processing using SQLite.